# Capistrano deploy:assets:precompile failed on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm getting error on running this tasks: 
Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile

```
Error:
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as deployer@**.**.**.***: rake exit status: 1
```

Here is my Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/rails/db'
require 'capistrano/rails/console'
require 'capistrano/upload-config'
require 'sshkit/sudo'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

This capfile running on Rails 4. I got the error when I migrated to rails 5.

Comment: Please do the next things, include the `deploy.rb` to the question, change the `log_level` to `:debug` in the `deploy.rb`, run deploy, show the full error trace.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my error: My capfile now looks like this

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/nginx'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/nginx'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/rails/db'
require 'capistrano/rails/console'
require 'capistrano/upload-config'
require 'sshkit/sudo'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

I removed this line for asset compilation

```
 require 'capistrano/rails
```

And replaced to

```
 require 'capistrano/rails/migrations
```